# Unable to run get .exe file from assembly NASM

Tags: assembly, gcc, compilation, exe, nasm

Recently I'm trying to learn Assembly but I got stuck from creating an EXE file from it. It keeps making errors although I've try to research about it a lot.

I've read a lot of tutorial on the Internet about "How to run a assembly files", "How to compile Assembly with NASM", "Using gcc to run Assembly files",... and I'm currently using MinGW from CodeBlocks and NASM trying to complile it. I've successed to  create one .obj file by the `nasm -f hello.asm` command. But then I got stuck with the next one, I used the command `gcc hello.obj -o hello.exe` trying to create an .exe file. And I got this error:

```
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `hello.obj' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output hello.obj:hello.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_printf' C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I researched some more on the Internet but I was unable to find anyone who have the same question as me. I am also sure that there is nothing wrong with the `%PATH%` system varibles. And I am also sure that there is no errors in my file (it is from [this tutorial site](https://labs.bilimedtech.com/nasm/windows-install/3.html) in case you need it).

Thank you!

Comment: You can't link 32 bit object to a 64-bit application.  Your GCC is defaulting to 64-bit. If you want a 64-biit app have you tried `nasm -fwin64 hello.asm` to gnerate a 64-bit Windows object and then do `gcc hello.obj -o hello.exe`

Comment: Now it says sth about _printf

`hello.obj:hello.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to _printf'
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to WinMain
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: I didn't review the tutorial. You should put the code you use inside the question. But clearly the problem is the tutorial is for producing 32-bit Windows apps. If you want a 32-bit app you can generate a 32-bit object with `nasm -fwin32 hello.asm` and then try using your GCC to produce a 32-bit app with `gcc -m32 hello.obj -o hello.exe`